# Convert 2 letter country code to country name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a big list of countries, the user selects which country they are from, I then save the 2 letter code to the database. When I later want to display which country that user is from on another page I can get the 2 letter code from the database, but how should I convert it back to the name of the country? It seems such a waste to have a big switch statement?

```
<select name='country' value={country} onChange={onChange}>
                <option value=''>Select...</option>
                <option value='AX'>Aaland Islands</option>
                <option value='AF'>Afghanistan</option>
                <option value='AL'>Albania</option>
                <option value='DZ'>Algeria</option>
                <option value='AS'>American Samoa</option>
                <option value='AD'>Andorra</option>
                <option value='AO'>Angola</option>
                <option value='AI'>Anguilla</option>
                <option value='AQ'>Antarctica</option>
                <option value='AG'>Antigua And Barbuda</option>
```

Comment: Use a map, both to generate the options, and to decode back.

Comment: Is your question "how to avoid writing the country name in the HTML and then again somewhere else?" The answer is to write a dictionary using an object or `Map`, then dynamically generate the HTML with it as well as using it to look up the country name for your other code.

Comment: @DaveNewton is a map really necessary? I feel like this would be a better case for an object with `{value: "Country Name"}` since the order of entries isn't really important.

Comment: Just an idea. But you could also keep a reference table in your database that has the country code & name.  F.e. `REF_COUNTRIES`. 
 Then when retrieving the country code from the user the SQL can just join to the reference table to get the country name. The code could even be the primary key of that reference table.

Comment: @MichaelOssig I was speaking generically.

Comment: So import something like this? 
`{
AX: {
      name: 'Aaland Islands'
    },
AF: {
      name: 'Afghanistan'
    }
}...` then map over it to make all the options?

Answer (score -1):

why don't you try to use a SELECT CASE

CASE
    WHEN condition1 THEN result1
    WHEN condition2 THEN result2
    WHEN conditionN THEN resultN
    ELSE result
END;